# ULS and Multiple WFEs

Tags: 2010, logging, server-farm, uls

If a farm has multiple WFEs do they have the same ULS logging content replicated across both?

Or does each have its own set of logs?

Straight forward enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each SharePoint Server only logs message due to code running on it in ULS. So you'll have different content on each.

You can use the PowerShell cmdlet [Merge-SPLogFile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607721.aspx) to collect information from all servers